# When i press my spinner i see my data, but when i try to select it, it doesn't set the data?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I am trying to make a spinner which takes data from a Realtime Firebase Database. I extract the data just fine in my log statements and i also see my data when i press my dropdown. But when i try to select something in my spinner it doesn't set the data. Also when i try to call my getSelectedItem() method it gives me the error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference`

In the logs i write there is no null values, therefore i am quite confused as to why i am getting this kind of error

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.example.bankapp.BankAccount;
import com.example.bankapp.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TransferOwnAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner accountFrom, accountTo;
    private EditText transferAmount;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transfer_own_account);
        init();
        loadAccounts();

    }

    public void transferMoney(View view) {
        Log.d("grinern", "olool"+accountFrom.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    public void loadAccounts() {
        Intent getIntent = getIntent();
        String userCPR = getIntent.getStringExtra("CPR");
        DatabaseReference dbref = database.getReference("usersbankaccounts/" + userCPR);
        dbref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DatabaseReference bankaccounts = database.getReference("bankaccounts/" + data.getKey());
                    Log.d("grinern", data.getKey());
                    bankaccounts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            BankAccount bankAccount = dataSnapshot.getValue(BankAccount.class);
                            accounts.add(bankAccount);
                            Log.d("grinern", ""+accounts);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                Log.d("grinern", ""+accounts);

                ArrayAdapter<BankAccount> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, accounts);
                accountFrom.setAdapter(adapter);
                accountTo.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void init() {
        this.accountFrom = findViewById(R.id.transferFromSpinner);
        this.accountTo = findViewById(R.id.transferToSpinner);
        this.transferAmount = findViewById(R.id.transferAmount);
        this.database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    }
}
```

It should select whatever i press in my dropdown spinner and print that in my log which is called in my transferMoney() method

Below is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".TransferOwnAccount">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/transferButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/contrast_background"
        android:text="@string/transfer"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:typeface="serif"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/transferToSpinner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.006"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transferToTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="@string/transfer_to"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:fontFamily="serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/transferFromSpinner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transferFromTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="@string/transfer_from"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:fontFamily="serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/transferAmount" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transferTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="@string/transfer_money"
        android:textColor="#F9FAF9"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:fontFamily="serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/transferAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/choose_amount"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/choose_amount"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:typeface="serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/transferTitle"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/transferFromSpinner"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/transferFromTitle" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/transferToSpinner"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/transferToTitle" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the JSON from my Firebase Database.

```
{
  "bankaccounts" : {
    "126" : {
      "accNumber" : "126",
      "balance" : 0,
      "title" : "Default"
    },
    "127" : {
      "accNumber" : "127",
      "balance" : 0,
      "title" : "Budget"
    },
    "128" : {
      "accNumber" : "128",
      "balance" : 0,
      "title" : "Pension"
    }
  },
  "nextNumber" : "128",
  "users" : {
    "1111111111" : {
      "address" : "qwe",
      "cpr" : "1111111111",
      "email" : "qwe",
      "firstname" : "qwe",
      "lastname" : "qwe",
      "password" : "111111",
      "phonenumber" : "793"
    }
  },
  "usersbankaccounts" : {
    "1111111111" : {
      "126" : "Default Account",
      "127" : "Budget Account",
      "128" : "Pension Account"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: At which line of code are ypu getting that error?

Comment: It's hard to say precisely what is going on, since there's UI interaction involved. But you might want to set a breakpoint inside `transferMoney` and see what happens when you run the code in a debugger, and select an item in the spinner.

Comment: when did you call transferMoney in that code ?

Comment: Getting the error on the first line of my transferMoney() method. @AlexMamo

Comment: Calling the transferMoney() on an onClick button in my layout. @ismailalaoui

Comment: Are you sure `accountFrom.getSelectedItem()` is not `null`? I'm affraid it is, right?

Comment: Yeah that is null. This is what i am confused about, because in my log statement where i print out my accounts it isn't null. Also when i press the spinner i see the options of the spinner, but thenit wont select anything inside the spinner

Comment: @SeanD'Arcy so where is the onclick definition in your code part ?

Comment: can you share your database json related to the question?

Comment: @ismailalaoui Ah, forgot to add my layout file. I've added it now. By using the design in Android Studio, you can just go to the layout file and add an onClick to a button or whatever you'd like.

Comment: @Zuhrain Yeah, just added. Thanks!

Comment: you didn't initialize the transfer button. @SeanD'Arcy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your bankaccounts arraylist to static (To make sure its the same even if the state changes)

And then I moved the adapter as a field and initialized it in the init method, Check the code I provided:

```
package com.example.bankapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.example.bankapp.BankAccount;
import com.example.bankapp.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TransferOwnAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner accountFrom, accountTo;
    private EditText transferAmount;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    static  ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<BankAccount> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transfer_own_account);
        init();
        loadAccounts();

    }

    public void transferMoney(View view) {
        Log.d("test", "olool" + accountFrom.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    public void loadAccounts() {
        Intent getIntent = getIntent();
        String userCPR = getIntent.getStringExtra("CPR");
        DatabaseReference dbref = database.getReference("usersbankaccounts/" + userCPR);
        dbref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DatabaseReference bankaccounts = database.getReference("bankaccounts/" + data.getKey());
                    Log.d("test", data.getKey());
                    bankaccounts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            BankAccount bankAccount = dataSnapshot.getValue(BankAccount.class);
                            accounts.add(bankAccount);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            Log.d("test", "" + accounts);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                Log.d("test", "" + accounts);


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void init() {
        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, accounts);
        this.accountFrom = findViewById(R.id.transferFromSpinner);
        this.accountTo = findViewById(R.id.transferToSpinner);
        this.transferAmount = findViewById(R.id.transferAmount);
        this.database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        this.accountFrom.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.accountTo.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Then you need to make sure you have a toString() method in your bankaccount

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + "--- " +accNumber + "  " + balance ;
    }
```

This should do the trick :)